Off-topic migration requests Cryptography
In this answer JNat told on Grace Notes:

Just make a meta thread demonstrating the need, anyone can do it.
  We'll then review it and then enable the path if it seems appropriate.

In Cryptography, we often see questions related to Math, Security, and StackOverflow. We can say off-topic by selecting flagging->off-topic-> ...asking on StackOverflow... but this is not migration and only for StackOverflow.
We need more migration options other than our Meta. These are most common that having these will be nicer for our site both for especially new users and administrators;

Mathematics
StackOverflow
Information Security (they have Cryptography as off-topic, but we don't have)

Fewer commons are;

Serverfault
Computer Science

In the current options; the close votes are confusing. We even don't have;

blatantly off-topic in Cryptography. Adding this also will be helpful. 


During the last month we had about 3 migrations to SO and 3 to InfoSec and 0 to math. I don't see a strong need there.

I can say that some of them are not migrated since we could not find a flag and some of us stayed silent about it? For example, this was definitely Math? And some of them just closed instead of migration? And at Math the answer

Regarding your other request, I'll schedule a new iteration of close-vote reason updates for early 2019, after the mod election is over and after the homework policy is settled (which is delayed due to the election).

still here, off-topic but not migrated,

@SEJPM A lot of questions never reach the migration stage even though they are on-topic here and they would have been fine for the target site. It also matters how many bad flags for migrations you're getting: how often do you get flags asking for a migration that shouldn't be performed (because the question is on-topic, or is low-quality, or would be off-topic on the target site)?

Oops, I meant “even though they are off-topic here”.

@kelalaka Cryptography is not strictly off-topic on [security.se], but any crypto that requires domain-specific expertise or more than trivial math and cryptography theory is migrated.

@forest I know from the first hand, but, thanks for the clarification. My point is Information Security has a menu option but we don't

Have we really grown to the point where the moderators are too busy to handle migrations? I suspect not, in which case the real issue is that we should communicate better that "flag for moderator attention and request migration" is a perfectly reasonable thing to do.

You can always raise a flag asking for mod attention, and simply write you think the Q should be migrated to some other SE site (by naming the potential target site). 



That tended to work flawlessly up until today.
edit
As thw comment exchange between kelalaka and Ilmari correctly reminded me to mention (thanks) :
Be sure to leave a comment at the question too, so the asker knows that you think there's a problem. Sometimes, things can be pulled on-topic after some clarifying back-and-forth. Also, it helps mods to assess the flag reasoning more quickly.
As always at this site: communication is key — so, 
always comment before flagging.


The OP and others, AFAIK, won't see this flag. 2) If it writes after the flag as Question suits for the site x (as similar in the duplicate flag) will be very nice 3) Mod can wait for the agreement that will reduce the mod time?


@kelalaka: You can, and probably should, also post a comment for the benefit of the OP.

@kelalaka Indeed. Somehow, I assumed that. My bad for not mentioning it. After all, communication is key in many situations at this site. (edited my answer accordingly)

Thanks for the reminder @ilmarikaronen.

Here a small migrated list starts now. The dates are the post dates. This list doesn't contain the posts that the OP deleted himself when we said off-topic.
StackOverflow

30/11/2018 https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/64441/using-webcrypto-to-generate-ecdh-key-from-pbkdf2
12/11/2018 https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/63924/writing-aes-ctr-decryption-routine-in-python
15/12/2018 https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/64886/bit-order-in-sha-256 (on Hold)
15/12/2018 https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/64888/how-to-encrypt-form-data-or-prevent-it-to-be-unseen-in-network-resources-of-brow (on Hold)
15/12/2018 https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/65892/why-are-crypto-hashes-with-the-same-parameters-equal? (deleted by the user to migrate to StackOverflow )
28/12/2108 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53950006/how-does-libgcrypt-increment-the-counter-for-ctr-mode
03/01/2019 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54021467/maskgenalgorithm-for-rsa-signature-with-pkcs1-pss-padding
03/01/2019 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54025771/digital-signature-verification-failed-using-sha256withrsa-in-python
08/01/2019 https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/66329/rsa-does-not-decrypt-correctly-in-java? (deleted by the user to migrate)

Information security

13/12/2018 Creating a login system
13/12/2018 How secure is pdf password protection?
29/11/2018 https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/64409/difference-between-secure-boot-and-attestation
13/11/2018 https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/63952/how-to-choose-between-password-derivation-or-encryption
25/12/208 https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/66089/how-much-less-secure-is-a-password-with-a-repetitive-pattern-of-characters (self copied)

SuperUser

28/11/2018 https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/64394/verifying-the-encryption-cipher-used-in-kleopatra
22/12/2018 Trying to verify a download signature with PGP, but getting "no signed data" when passing in the .asc file?
31/12/208 https://superuser.com/questions/1389112/is-there-a-way-of-bitwise-decrypting-a-corrupt-bitlocker-encrypted-raw-hdd-ima

Unix

16/12/2018 https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/489324/writing-to-root-workspace-doesnt-break-the-files-inside-encrypted-partition

Mathematics

12/12/2018 Proof that legendre symbol $\Big(\frac{a}{p}\Big)$ is $a^{\frac{p-1}{2}}$

Software Recommendations 

03/01/2019 https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/54282/hybrid-encryption-tools-besides-openssl-and-gnupg

